# Como trocar a cor de botões com o hover sobre apenas um botão (CSS)

Tags: css, css3, css-hover, background-color

Bom, meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho cinco botões, em ordem horizontal. Cada um tem uma cor específica no hover. Ao colocar o mouse sobre algum deles, **todos os outros *deveriam assumir* a cor que o selecionado tem**.

Eu consegui usar esse efeito com sucesso no primeiro botão, já que os demais mudaram de cor; ao aplicar o código nos outros, apenas os botões à frente (à direita) mudaram de cor, e não consigo fazer com que o botão anterior mude.

Pra demonstrar, vou simular o terceiro botão, chamarei de "box3".
Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
box3:hover ~ box1 {
    background-color:red;
}
box3:hover ~ box2 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

^ os dois acima são os que ficam à esquerda e não mudam de cor

```
box3:hover ~ box4 {
    background-color:red;
}
box3:hover ~ box5 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

obs: não coloquei o box3 para mudar de cor pois este é hover de outro elemento, então desnecessário.

Já tentei trocar o ~ por +, > e por espaço vazio também.
Valeu!!

Comment: Não conseguirá apenas com CSS, pois os seletores disponíveis só enxergam os elementos a frente do em questão. Para fazer isso acredito que precisará de JavaScript.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sei lá se fica maçante/complicado da maneira que fiz, mas foi possivel com `pointer-events` :)

Answer (score 2):

Isto só irá afetar os elementos a direita do elemento selecionado:

```css
[class*=box]:hover, [class*=box]:hover ~ [class*=box] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>
```

Creio que **não seja possível** pegar os elementos anteriores, apenas os próximos, para pegar todos que pertencem a um elemento "pai" será necessário JavaScript/jquery, no entanto é possível **forçar** um pouco o efeito se aplicar `:hover` no elemento `parent`, assim (no caso criei um elemento "pai" chamado `.row`):

```css
.row:hover > [class*=box] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>
```

No entanto o efeito ocorrerá em qualquer área do `.row`, então você pode usar `pointer-events: none;` e `pointer-events: auto;`:

```css
/* remove a interação do toch e mouse do elemento "pai"*/
.row {
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* restaura a interação do toch e mouse a todos elementos "filhos", incluindo os botões e outros */
.row > * {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* aplica o vermelhor ao passar o mouse sob o elemento pai mas somente quando for possivel "interagir" com pointer-events */
.row:hover > [class*=box] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>
```

Mas é **importante** notar que o `pointer-events` afeta o touch e o mouse/rato de outros elementos filhos, isso claro pode ser resolvido aplicando aos elementos filhos necessários o `pointer-events: auto;`, por motivo usei `> *`

```
.row > * {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

---

### Extra

Se cada elemento botão tiver uma cor será necessário fazer isto separadamente, por exemplo:

```css
.row {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.row > * {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.row:hover > .box1 { background-color: red; }
.row:hover > .box2 { background-color: blue; }
.row:hover > .box3 { background-color: black; }
.row:hover > .box4 { background-color: orange; }
.row:hover > .box5 { background-color: magenta; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <button class="box1">foo</button>
   <button class="box2">foo</button>
   <button class="box3">foo</button>
   <button class="box4">foo</button>
   <button class="box5">foo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu estive usando o # enquanto fazia o código, só não usei na demonstração aqui do Stack mesmo ^^
Se não tivesse usado, bem sei que os botões da frente também não mudariam de cor, já que o meu problema são os botões à esquerda daquele em que eu passarei o ponteiro do mouse em cima

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme! Pensei que fosse simples o suficiente pro CSS, mas pelo jeito vou ter que enfrentar o JavaScript. Até pesquisei e achei formas de influenciar o elemento pai a partir do filho, mas não soube o que fazer com aquele código de JQuery hahaha
Você sabe se existe alguma previsão de quando estarão disponíveis os seletores nível 4 em navegadores?

Comment: @AndréCiappina adicionei um exemplo 100% com CSS, removi a parte sobre o possivel erro dos seletores, e adicionei explicações sobre o funcionamento do código que criei, espero que lhe seja util.

Comment: Nesse caso, a cor será sempre a mesma independente do botão com hover, correto?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso facilmente é resolvido com uma classe extra que represente uma cor, no entanto não me parece ser o que o AP pediu, se for o caso edito e adiciono um exemplo.

Comment: Eu havia entendido isso no trecho "cada um tem uma cor específica no hover". Aliás, o `pointer-events` serviu para o *hover* responder somente nos elementos filhos, entendi bem?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss [editado] sim o pointer-events garante que a interação do touch ou mouse ocorra somente aonde foi setado *pointer-events: **auto**;*, no caso `> *`, ps: Resposta editada.

Comment: @AndréCiappina editado para acaso necessite de múltiplas/diferentes cores para cada botão.

Comment: Primeiro uso real de `pointer-events` que vi, interessante até. +1